# What does mAP mean?

Tags: neural-networks, terminology

Some machine learning papers, such as [this one](https://pjreddie.com/media/files/papers/YOLOv3.pdf) (see its abstract) express results on certain datasets as a percentage value called mAP. Could anyone explain the meaning of mAP?

Comment: Could you please show us a source where it appears?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

mAP probably stands for mean Average Precision. The AP provides a measure of quality across all recall levels for single class classification, it can be seen as the area under the precision-recall curve. Then the mAP is the mean of APs in multi-class classification.